# Why we are using transactions in JDBC?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, transactions

MY jdbc program code with and with out transaction is mentioned below.

**WITHOUT TRANSACTION IN JDBC**

```
stmt = conn.createStatement();

      System.out.println("creating statement....");
      String sql;
      sql = " INSERT INTO testing VALUES (3,  'Rita', 'Tez','vizag')";
      stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
      System.out.println("deleted.....");
      sql = "SELECT s_no,s_name,s_group,s_area  from testing group by s_no,s_name,s_group, s_area";
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
      while(rs.next()){


         String s_name = rs.getString("s_name");


         System.out.println("employees names:" +s_name);
      }
```

**WITH TRANSACTION IN JDBC**

```
conn.setAutoCommit(false);



      System.out.println("Creating statement...");
      stmt = conn.createStatement(
                           ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                           ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);


      System.out.println("Inserting one row....");
      String SQL = "INSERT INTO testing " +
                    "VALUES (3,  'Rita', 'Tez','vizag')";
      stmt.executeUpdate(SQL);  


      SQL = "INSERT INTO testing " +
                    "VALUES (4,  'Sita', 'Singh','hyd')";
      stmt.executeUpdate(SQL);


      System.out.println("Commiting data here....");
      conn.commit();


      String sql = "SELECT  s_no,s_name,s_group,s_area FROM testing group by s_no,s_name,s_group,s_area ";
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
      System.out.println("List result set for reference....");
      printRs(rs);


      rs.close();
      stmt.close();
      conn.close();
   }catch(SQLException se){

      se.printStackTrace();

      System.out.println("Rolling back data here....");
      try{
         if(conn!=null)
            conn.rollback();
      }catch(SQLException se2){
         se2.printStackTrace();
      }

   }catch(Exception e){

      e.printStackTrace();
   }finally{

      try{
         if(stmt!=null)
            stmt.close();
      }catch(SQLException se2){
      }
      try{
         if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         se.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

}

   public static void printRs(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException{

      rs.beforeFirst();
      while(rs.next()){

         int s_no = rs.getInt("s_no");
         String s_name = rs.getString("s_name");
         String s_group = rs.getString("s_group");
         String s_area = rs.getString("s_area");


         System.out.print("s_no: " + s_no);
         System.out.print(", s_name: " + s_name);
         System.out.print(", s_group: " + s_group);
         System.out.println(", s_area: " + s_area);
     }
     System.out.println();
   }
}
```

Both transactions are  returning same results,then y we use `TRANSACTIONS` in `JDBC`.Please clarify my doubt.

Comment: The same reasons why you would use transactions in any other use of a database. To commit or rollback a set of statements as one unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second example transaction are being used because multiple inserts are being executed as part of the transaction.  The transaction is capable of rolling back the first insert if the second insert fails.  It makes both operations one atomic unit.

Comment: your meaning is better to use transaction in JDBC.Isn't it?

Comment: There is any another way to write TRANSACTION'S in very simple way.Please suggest me i thought my transaction process code is very large,can u simplify my code ?

Answer (score 1):

JDBC Connection is in auto-commit mode, by default auto-commit mode, 
 then every SQL statement is committed to the database upon its completion.
 with below reasons  we want to turn off auto-commit and manage your own transactions:

- To increase performance
- To maintain the integrity of business processes

Transactions enable us to control if any  changes are applied to the database. It treats a single SQL statement or a group of SQL statements as one logical unit. If any statement fails, the whole transaction will fails.

To enable manual- transaction instead of the auto-commit mode of  JDBC driver use the Connection object's setAutoCommit() method. Once we  done with our changes and want to commit the changes then call commit() method. Otherwise, to roll back updates to the database made using the Connection named conn, use

```
 conn.rollback( );
```

Refer [transaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction)

Comment: wikipedia is well explaining

Comment: There is any another way to write TRANSACTION'S in very simple way.Please suggest me i thought my transaction process code is very large,can u simplify my code ?

Answer (score 0):

Transaction is not just about commit/rollback.. It is just one property in ACID [Click](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)..